# Test coverage for MongoTempalte find method with query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, junit5, mongotemplate

I am trying to add test coverage for following method which query for latest log date. I am not able to mock `Query` and assert the result.

```
public MyLogData findLastLogDate() {
  Query query = new Query().with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "logDate"));
  return mongoTemplate.find(query, MyLogDate.class).get(0); //Aautowired MongoTemplate
}
```

For test I am trying something like this

```
@Mock
private MongoTempalte mogoTemplate;

@InjectMocks
private MyClassToTest testMe;

@Test
void testQuery() {
  List<MyLogData> logDataList = new ArrayList<>();
  MyLogDate myLogDate = MyLogDate.builder()....build();
  logDataList.add(myLogData);

  when(mongoTemplate.find(mockQuery, mockMyLogData)).thenReturn(logDataList); //how to mock Query and MyLogData here?

  MyLogData result = testMe.findLastLogDate();

  assertEquals(myLogDate, result);
}
```

Any suggestion?